# Visualizing multiple variables in one plot seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am fairly new in python and I have been playing around trying to generate some plots. I have the following data.

```
data = {'FA':[38,27],'NV':[8,2],'PA':[20.4,12.6],'DY':[5.9,6.9],'SL':[30.6,20.6],'AP':[16.6,2],'CO':[9,15.9],'DI':[5.9,12.5],'FI':[15.6,32], 'currentuse':[0,1]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['FA','NV','PA','DY','SL','AP','CO','DI','FI','currentuse'])

`data.head()`

   FA    NV  PA   DY      SL      AP    CO    DI    FI  currentuse
0   38   8  20.4  5.9   30.6    16.6  9.0   5.9    15.6    0
1   27   2  12.6  6.9   20.6    2.0  15.9   12.5   32.0    1
```

Which is a subset of a larger dataset with more variables. Each column in the data above is the mean of a certain score from the larger population and the column `currentuse` is the use of a drug (0:No, 1:Yes). In reality I have the score for each subject (about 150 subjects), but I am showing here the group means.

With this I created the following plot:

`sns.catplot(data=data, kind='point')`
[Fig1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTz18.png)

However, I would like to create a plot similar to this one which was created in matplotlib but I cannot figure a way to create it in **seaborn**:
[Fig2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7WnY.png)

When I try `sns.catplot(data=data, kind='point', hue='currentuse')`

I get this error:

> ValueError: Cannot use `hue` without `x` or `y`

Which I understand, since I am running the plot on the "dataset" rather than on a variable X or Y. Then I tried `sns.catplot(data=main_df, x=['FA','NV','PA','DY','SL','AP','CO','DI','FI'], kind='point', hue='currentuse')` but providing a list of variables is not allowed in **seaborn**.

Although, I successfully created the plot by doing a lot of steps: creating summary statistics (means, standard errors), subsets of variables per group and subplots in matplotlib, I was wondering if there is a way to create it in **seaborn** since it will involve significantly less lines of code which it will be more efficient.

Thank you all!

Comment: You say you successfully created the plot by doing a lot of steps, could you post the code?

Comment: From the main dataset I got the groups:
`users = df['currentuse']==1`
Then I obtained the means and Confidence intervals for each group:
`sympt_musers = sympt.loc[users].mean()`

`sympt_seu= (sympt.loc[users].sem())*1.960`

`sympt_mnu = sympt.loc[users==False].mean()`

`sympt_senu = (sympt.loc[users==False].sem())*1.960`

_Note: I acknowledge that the steps above could have been done more efficiently probably by creating a loop._

Comment: Followed, I created the variables and the plot:
`sympt_vars=['FA','NV','PA','DY','SL','AP','CO','DI','FI']`

`fig, ax = plt.subplots()`
`ax.plot(sympt_vars, sympt_musers, 'bo' ,label='Users')`
`ax.errorbar(sympt_vars, sympt_musers, yerr=sympt_seu)`

`ax.plot(sympt_vars, sympt_mnu, 'ro' ,label='Non-users')`
`ax.errorbar(sympt_vars, sympt_mnu, yerr=sympt_senu)`
`ax.set_title('QLQ C-30 scale by cannabis usage')`
`ax.legend()`

Some steps seem redundant like pulling the mean of each variable and confidence intervals, given that **seaborn** plots these parameters.